# Foreach is not working in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

How can I use foreach for this? I would like to display all the names.

```
test: [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Tname1"
}, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Tname2"
}]
```

It doesn't work:

```
this.test.forEach(function(s){
    console.log(s.name);
});
```

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Also, when you make a question showing negative factorial mole effort, then no one would bother aiding.

Comment: No need for any hate speech. You are too harsh. @Bonatti

Comment: @franc Where is the hate speech? I failed to see it. That comment was posted, before any edits to the question (and you can see the revision). It showed 0 effort, in attempting to solve, 0 effort to google an answer, and the people on this forum are not free-programmers. I just stated the obvious. Even still, I pointed resources for the person to read... Where is the harsh/hateful speech in that?

Answer (score 5):

I think that you need this:

```
test = [
  {
      id: "1",
      name: "Tname1"
  },
  {
      id: "2",
      name: "Tname2"
  }
];
```

In TypeScript `:` is to define the type of an element. For example:

```
test: any[] = [ ... ];
```